# С++ олимпиадная задача

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Старый пират Пью спрятал свое золото, но для надежности не в одном месте, а частями в нескольких тайниках. Но чтобы не забыть места хранения клада он составил карту. Карта представляет собой упорядоченную последовательность тайников в каждом из которых записано целое число. Положительное число, записанное в тайнике, обозначает номер тайника, к которому следует перейти; отрицательное число - часть золотого клада, стоимость которого равна абсолютному значению содержимого этого тайника. Выбрав золото из текущего тайника, искатель переходит к следующему тайнику по списку. Если искатель клада добрался до пустого тайника или до последнего в списке, то это означает, что все доступное золото собрано и можно уносить ноги, пока цел (за золотом пирата Пью охотятся и другие искатели). Но если искатель вскроет тайник, содержимое которого равно 666, то сработает капкан и ... поминай, как звали:(
>
> Определить общую стоимость клада. Если искатель клада попал в капкан, то вывести "RIP". Искатель начинает поиск клада с первого тайника. После вскрытия тайник обнуляется.
>
> Во входном потоке в первой строке задано натуральное число N (N < 1000). Во второй строке целые числа, перечисленные через пробел - карта тайников. Значение, записанное в тайнике задано в диапазоне -32000 <= Ai <= N.
>
> Например,
>
> ```
> 8
> 5 4 -10 666 3 8 6 7
> ```
>
> В выходной поток вывести единственное целое число или слово "RIP".
>   Например,
>
> ```
> RIP
> ```

Хочу сам прийти к решению, но торможу на одном месте(
Понятно, что нужно обращаться к рекурсивной функции из цикла, которая будет возвращать следующую подсказку до тех пор, пока не возвратит либо 666, либо отрицательное значение.

В целом представляю решение так:

- инициализация sum=0
- создаём массив и заполняем его
- проходим в цикле значения массива

  - вызываем рекурсивную функцию, передаём в неё массив, текущий элемент (значение)

    1. функция вызывает сама себя, если она возвращает положительное значение !=666
    2. если 666 выходим из функции, цикла, пишем RIP, break
    3. если вернёт <0 тогда sum+=abs(), continue
- когда цикл завершён выводим сумму

Столкнулся с тремя явными проблемами:

1. Возможна бесконечная рекурсия, нужно как-то из неё выйти
2. Нужно как-то пометить, что клад мы забрали, помечаем нулём?
3. Если функция вызывает сама себя, то как она может  вернуться к циклу???

Получается, что считать сумму нужно в самой функции, но тогда смысл цикла заключается в том, чтобы переходить к другому элементу, если столкнулись с нулём и контролировать 666

Какая-то рекурсия мыслей получается...
В то же время эта задача в архиве задач идёт сразу после задач на индексацию, сбивает с толку, может лучше создать кучу массивов, или как-либо пересортировать исходный?

Как Вы считаете, я на верном пути, или упускаю что-то очевидное?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем тут вам рекурсия...

Comment: *2. Нужно как-то пометить, что клад мы забрали, помечаем нулём?* — *После вскрытия тайник обнуляется*

Comment: Один массив и два указателя, и прыгай до конца (или до могилки)... Делов-то... *Если искатель клада добрался до пустого тайника или до последнего в списке* Пустой - это ноль? последний - это как определяется, позиционно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде простая задача (или я что-то неправильно понял), бесконечных циклов не будет, т. к. тайник после посещения обнуляется. Можно и рекурсией, но зачем?

Псевдокод:

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
while (i < n && a[i] != 0 && a[i] != 666)
{
    if (a[i] > 0)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = 0;
        i = temp - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sum -= a[i];
        a[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
if (i >= n || a[i] == 0)
    print(sum);
else
    print("RIP");
```

Comment: Немного не понял, как вообще можно обойтись без рукурсии

Comment: Ну я же написал код, вы пробовали его?